# Change Contents default header Type

Tags: types, header, typo3

I already created another question about tt_address. Now my question is about tt_content.

Since I've just upgraded from TYPO3 6 to TYPO3 9 I'm new to all things that were changed.

I have the problem that all my headings are displayed as H2. I could change it manually in all elements to H1 but that's not a thing for me. I want to set the standard Heading Type to H1. But all TypoScripts I found on the Internet do not work for me.

TypoScript that don't work for me:

```
content.defaultHeaderType = 1

styles.content.defaultHeaderType = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default via page-TSconfig in your root page:

```
TCAdefaults.tt_content.header_layout = 1
```

But '1' should already be default (if not changed manually) and this does only affect the pre-selected option (header layout dropdown) of new content elements. If you would like to change all existing headings, this would be possible f. e. via PhpMyAdmin

```
UPDATE `tt_content` SET `header_layout` = '1' WHERE `header_layout` = '2'.
```

If you would like to render headers with header_layout '2' as `<h1>`, you could edit the fluid-template /Partials/Header/Header.html (do not edit original, make a copy instead: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/Index.html ).

```
<f:case value="2">
    <h1 class="{positionClass}">
        <f:link.typolink parameter="{link}">{header}</f:link.typolink>
    </h1>
</f:case>
```

If you change the templates, you may consider renaming the available options. This is also possible via page-TSconfig

```
TCEFORM{
    tt_content{
        header_layout{
            altLabels.1 = (h1) Headline
            altLabels.2 = ex (h2) Sub-Headline – NOW H1
            altLabels.3 = (h3) Sub-Sub-Headline
            removeItems = 0,4,5
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your Constant ts

```
styles.content.defaultHeaderType = 1
```

Comment: Did you check in the TypoScript Object Browser that `styles.content.defaultHeaderType` is really set?

Comment: Yes I had already check first in my site after that post this answer

Comment: Have you enabled fluid_styled_content in TypoScript?

Answer (score 0):

In fluid_styled_content the default header type can be set in setup.ts

```
lib.contentElement.settings.defaultHeaderType = 1
```